# iPhone: What gets called after viewDidLoad before viewWillAppear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

Really strange behaviour here.
I've got a view with a scroll view inside, which contains my interface.

In my `viewDidLoad`, I set the frame of my scrollView to have an origin of 0,0.

I log the origin at the end of my `viewDidLoad`, and it's 0.
However, at the start of my `viewWillAppear`, the origin is -20.
Does anyone know what kind of method could get called that would do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the line where you log the origin? it's funny that the status bar is 20px, but that doesn't explain the minus sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find out what it could be, you can try registering your view for key value observing, as described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

You can register to listen for changes to the frame property, and then set a breakpoint in the observe method which should let you see exactly what the stacktrace is for when your origin is set to the strange value.

Comment: +1 for the the awesome answer and for the EarthBound avatar....ok mostly the EarthBound avatar

Answer (score 32):

You are correct with the current method precedence:

```
-(void)loadView;
-(void)viewDidLoad;
-(void)viewWillAppear;
-(void)viewDidAppear;
```

Is there perhaps a rotation call or some other method in the way, such as `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation;` for example? Also, is this scroll view part of a controller that's loaded from a nib file?

Comment: yes... I think it might be to do with the nib... how could I find that out?

Comment: Are you using the -(void)awakeFromNib: method? If not, throw it in and consider moving some calculations in there.... I forgot how this method fits in with my list above.

Answer (score 2):

20 pixel discrepancies and nib files always seem to be woe, but with Interface Builder and status bars. Are you setting up the nib with the same status-bar state as what your using in your app?

If you've hidden your status bar in your app, have you done the same in Interface Builder?

Comment: 20 px change sounds VERY like the status bar has been hidden between those two events.