# How to make an iOS page with keypad up?

Tags: ios, keyboard, pageload, becomefirstresponder

I want to create a text message page and want to see the keyboard on page load. This is what I have which doesn't work. Can you find what I'm doing wrong?

**In my header file:**

```
@interface taskViewController : ViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *taskDescription;

    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

**In my .m file:**

```
#import "taskViewController.h"

@interface taskViewController ()
@end

@implementation taskViewController
    @synthesize taskDescription = _taskDescription;

    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [_taskDescription becomeFirstResponder];
 }
@end
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but it might not be helping
1. You shouldn't define `viewWillAppear` in you `.h`
2. Don't call `super`
3. Change `_taskDescription` to `self.taskDescription` and move it to viewDidAppear

Comment: How are you creating the layout for the ViewController? Is taskDescription defined in IB or Storyboard and then hooked up to the IBOutLet correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
[self.view addSubview:_taskDescription];
```

before calling UIResponder. As Apple says in the UIResponder reference, object must be added to the view hierarchy before calling UIResponder.

So your -viewWillAppear: method will be:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.view addSubview:_taskDescription];
    [_taskDescription becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

More info at the [UIResponder Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder)

Comment: He is doing this through a .xib file and so manually adding the subview is not at all recommended. The subview will be added at some point, that's why I recommend waiting until it is added through loading the .xib fully.

Answer (score -1):

In `viewWillAppear:` the `tackDescription` had obviously not yet fully loaded and may be `nil`.

**My recommendation** would be to move the call of `[self.taskDescription becomeFirstResponder]` to `viewDidLoad`.

In `viewDidLoad` you can know for sure that the entire view has loaded and everything had been added appropriately.

Comment: according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821067/iphone-what-gets-called-after-viewdidload-before-viewwillappear viewWillAppear is called after viewDidLoad?

Comment: Not always. Just try it.