# Does the viewdidload method get called before the view appear?

Tags: ios

I've started learning IOS, I'm wondering does the `viewdidload:` method get called before the view appears on screen? The apple developer guide says this method gets called after the view is loaded into memory but I don't understand What "loaded into memory" means, does it mean the view doesn't appear on screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: What gets called after viewDidLoad before viewWillAppear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821067/iphone-what-gets-called-after-viewdidload-before-viewwillappear)

Comment: yes, please refer view controller life cycle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle

Answer (score 18):

> Does the viewdidload method get called before the view appears?

Yes.

Borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6821229/164998), view controller delegate method order is:

```
- (void)loadView;
- (void)viewDidLoad;
- (void)viewWillAppear;
- (void)viewDidAppear;
```

> What "loaded into memory" means?

It means when the object (view) is created. It is possible to create and show a view virtually at the same time. However, technically viewDidLoad will be called first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, viewDidLoad method is called before viewDidAppear:.

viewDidLoad and viewDidLoad: mean actually different things. You specify : if it has an argument, but viewDidLoad does not, just as a convention.

Loaded in memory means ready to use/display.

Comment: I don't type viewdidload: ,the moderator has modified.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called before. 
ViewDidAppear - it is called when the view is visible to the user, here is the place to start an animation or something like that.

More information about the view controller lifecycle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/3482000

Answer (score 0):

Yes viewdidload: is called before viewWillAppear:.
and The apple developer guide says this method gets called after the view is loaded into memory means,
The viewController in storyboard/XIB is loading into device memory. Other way we can say the user interface which i design into XIB or storyboard is loding into memory...